# puppet kick from master gets connection refused from agent

Tags: puppet

I have installed puppet agent (windows) and master successfully. When i download the node from agent it works fine  (`puppet agent -t` ) and the nodes are pulled successfully.

But when i trigger the same from the puppet master, i get  connection error as below.

```
Error: Host agent01 failed: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

I did a wireshark in agent machine and i could see the connection made to agent at port 8139 and is responded with a red ACK message.

Since the connection has reached the agent, am assuming agent rejected the connection. Could some one please help me fix this problem.

Puppet.conf at agent

```
[main]
server=puppetmaster.localsky.biz
autoflush=true
environment=production
pluginsync=true
listen = true
[agent]
```

auth.conf at agent:

```
path /
method find, search, save
auth yes
allow puppetmaster.localsky.biz
```

However, if i run `puppet agent --no-daemonize --debug` 
from the Powershell console, the build gets pushed successsfully.

So the failure happens only if run the agent from Puppet Agent as windows service.

Comment: `connection refused` quite distinctly indicates that the port in question is not open. Can you check the list of listening ports while the agent is running? (Also, make sure that the background agent *is* in fact running.) Failing all that, please add the output of `puppet agent --configprint all` to your question.

Comment: Thanks Felix... I just got an info that kick is not possible from the below link... Not sure of the credibility of the info though..
https://ask.puppet.com/question/14234/port-8139-not-opened-when-running-as-a-windows-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I landed up on the link below which says Kick is not possible for windows agents.  Not sure how true this is...

https://ask.puppet.com/question/14234/port-8139-not-opened-when-running-as-a-windows-service/

Comment: That answer was given by Josh Cooper from the Puppet core development team. I think it's quite credible :-)